# How to a dropdown list of element numbers in power bi using a table/matrix

Tags: excel, powerbi

I have a column of structure elements, ie, 1, 1.1, 2, 2.1, 2.1.1. How would I get the numbers with multiple levels (1.1, 2.1, 2.1.1) to be under their parent element (1) (2) on power bi using the table or matrix feature?

I tried to create level columns where if there number is 3.1.1 it would be Level1: 3 Level2: 1 Level3: 1, but it would not work.

Answer (score 0):

1. First extract the first character from the Text in Power Query
2. Filter the Table to contain non-blanks using CalculateTable in DAX
3. Take the Matrix visual and keep Two columns as rows

`let Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Ashok\Power BI\Stack Overflow\Data03jul23.xlsx"), null, true), Data_Sheet = Source{[Item="Data",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data], #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Data_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]), #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Promoted Headers", "Custom", each if Text.Contains(Text.From([Number]), ".") then Text.Start(Text.From([Number]), 1) else "") in #"Added Custom"`

[image]
[image]

Comment: How did you compute the custom column?

Comment: I created level1, 2, 3, 4 column from doing find and replace, I replaced the . with | and used DAX to compute the levels. Now it is not indenting like in the image.

Comment: Is there a way to get 2.1.1 under 2.1 as an indent?